# Weighted limits and Kan extension in Dist

Tags: ct.category-theory, limits-and-colimits, kan-extension

(noting $\otimes$ for composition in distributors, $\phi_f : A \nrightarrow B = B(-,f=)$ and $\phi^f : B \nrightarrow A = B(f-,=)$ the embeddings of a functor $f:A\to B$ in $Dist$, and $Dist(A,B) = [B^{op}\times A, V]$ for the category of distributors from $A \nrightarrow B$)

I  am looking at 2 universal properties:

- The UP of the weighted limit of a functor $D : A \to M $ and weights $J : A \nrightarrow B$ is, naturally for $m :1 \to M$ and $b : 1 \to B$

$$
 [1,M] (m,(Lim^JD)b) \simeq [A,V] (J(b,-), M(m,D -))
$$

which can be rewritten

$$
  Dist(B,M)(\phi_m\otimes\phi^b, \phi_{Lim^JD}) \simeq  Dist(A,M) (\phi_m\otimes \phi^b \otimes J, \phi_D )
$$

- The UP for the right kan extension in Dist $R : M^{op} \times B \to V$ of $M(-, D=) : M^{op}\times A \to V$ along $J:B^{op} \times A \to V$ is, for $H : M^{op}\times B \to V$

$$Dist(B, M)(H, Ran_{J}\phi_D) \simeq Dist(A,M)(H\otimes J, \phi_D)$$

When special cased to $H$ of the form $\phi_m \otimes \phi^b$, this gives the previous UP. So some $l : B \to M $ representing the right kan extension as $\phi_l \simeq  Ran_{J}\phi_D: B \nrightarrow M$ is required to verify more than the UP for $l : B \to M $ to be a weighted limit.

Is there a clever way to highlight the difference between a weighted limit and a representation of a right kan extension in $Dist$, which would shed lights on the difference of nature between the two ?

(Maybe some additional property which says when a weighted limit also a representation.. ? Or some case where one exist and not the other ?)

Comment: A pointwise right extension along $j \colon A \to B$ in $\mathrm{Cat}$ is precisely a limit weighted by the corepresentable $B(1, j)$, hence a right extension along $B(1, j)$ in $\mathrm{Dist}$. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: as far as a I understand, a pointwise kan extension is a weighted limit (a specific one, weighted by $\phi_j$). what I am trying to understand is the difference between weighted limits and (representation of) Kan extension in $Dist$, the bicategory of distributors.

Comment: (any limit weighted by $P$ has the property that evaluating it at a specific functor $b:X\to B$ is the limit weighted by $\phi^b \otimes P$. we get the limit formula when we choose a functor from $X=1$, to which pointwise extension also evaluate to)

Comment: With the corrected definition of weighted limits I don't see how a pointwise kan extension is one.. I will post a new question

Comment: Wood defines pointwise extensions in [Abstract pro arrows I](https://www.numdam.org/item/CTGDC_1982__23_3_279_0), as limits weighted by corepresentable distributors. If you look at the definition, it essentially coincides with the classical definition of pointwise right extension, e.g. [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Kan+extension#PointwiseByWeightedColimits).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I've followed your question exactly, so let me rephrase it to how I've understood it, and you can tell me if I've misunderstood. I shall use different letters to make sure I'm not accidentally using them inconsistently with your conventions.

For a functor $s \colon X \to Z$, I will denote by $s_* \colon X \nrightarrow Z$ the corepresentable distributor $Z({-}_2, s{-}_1)$.

The question essentially appears to be this:

> What is the relationship between right (Kan) extensions in the bicategory of distributors, and weighted limits in the 2-category of small categories?

As you say, a right extension in $\mathrm{Dist}$ is defined by the following universal property:
[image: Diagram expressing the equation below]
$$\mathrm{Dist}(Y, Z)(h, \mathrm{Ran}_g f) \cong \mathrm{Dist}(X, Z)(h \otimes g, f)$$

Now suppose we have a distributor (the *weight*) $\Psi \colon X \nrightarrow Y$ and a functor $s \colon X \to Z$ (the *diagram*). The *$\Psi$-weighted limit of $s$* is a functor $\{ \Psi, s \} \colon Y \to Z$, defined to satisfy $(\{ \Psi, s \})_* \cong \mathrm{Ran}_\Psi (s_*)$. The weighted limit thus satisfies the following universal property:
$$\mathrm{Dist}(Y, Z)(h, (\{ \Psi, s \})_*) \cong \mathrm{Dist}(X, Z)(h \otimes \Psi, s_*)$$
In other words, a weighted limit is precisely a corepresentable right extension along a corepresentable distributor.

One reference I find helpful for this topic is Wood's [Abstract pro arrows I](http://www.numdam.org/item/CTGDC_1982__23_3_279_0/), though this perspective also appears in other literature by Street, Betti, and others.

Comment: If that's the case, I used a wrong definition for weighted limit. Which only half surprises me as I was questioning the relevance of this definition.

Comment: Thank you for the reference